# Python Caesar cipher: How to continue?

Tags: python, caesar-cipher

I have to finish and upgrade this code. It deals with a Caesar cipher, with a key to find the encrypted word. Here is the program, if you can help me with like tell me what to add or anything. (Sorry for my English, I'm French.)

```
def caesar_crypt(input_str, key):
    output_str = ''
    for c in input_str:
        co = ord(c)
        # Only crypt capital letters
        if 65 <= ord(c) <= 90:
            co = co + key
            # Deal with when we go outside the alphabet
            if co > 90:
                co = co - 26
            elif co < 65:
                co = co + 26
        output_str += chr(co)
    return output_str

string_to_crypt = input("Enter the message you cant to crypt").upper()
key = int(input("Which key (integer between 1 and 25) do you want to use ?"))

print("The crypted text is the following")
print(caesar_crypt(string_to_crypt, key))
```

Comment: What problem are you having?  (Also, please indent your code with at least four spaces so it's shown as code)

Comment: I dont know how to do , where to begin

Comment: Hi DYO, welcome to StackOverflow, most likely nobody will solve your problem for you, you need to [show some research](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post specific questions. However, I think your problem is very well explained here: https://inventwithpython.com/chapter14.html